# How to make scrapy follow invalid links?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I use scrapy very often to check long lists of links whether they're available or dead.

My problem is when the link is incorrectly formatted for example doesn't start with http:// or https:// the crawler crashes.

```
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: http.www.gobiernoenlinea.gob.ve/noticias/viewNewsUser01.jsp?applet=1&id_noticia=41492
```

I read the list of links from pandas Series and check each of them. When the response is reachable I log it as "ok" otherwise as "dead".

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
from link_checker.items import LinkCheckerItem



class Checker(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "link_checker"


    def get_links(self):
        df = pd.read_csv(r"final_07Sep2018.csv")
        return df["Value"]

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = self.get_links()
        for url in urls.iteritems():
            index = {"index" : url[0]}
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url[1], callback=self.get_response, errback=self.errback_httpbin, meta=index, dont_filter=True)

    def get_response(self, response):
        url = response.url

        yield LinkCheckerItem(index=response.meta["index"], url=url, code="ok")

    def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
        yield LinkCheckerItem(index=failure.request.meta["index"], url=failure.request.url, code="dead")
```

I am still interested in spotting those incorrectly formatted urls. How can I validate them and yield "dead" for those as well?

Comment: Does wrapping your `yield` in `start_requests` with a `try/except ValueError` then yielding in the except `yield LinkCheckerItem(index=index['index'], url=url[1], code='invalid')` or similar work?

Comment: Also... you might want to consider if doing `method='HEAD'` is suitable if you're only interested in checking the server's going to respond to that URL in some way... will save getting the content of the page, bandwith and speed things up if you've no need for it.

Comment: try/except `ValueError` would be the best way (with maybe a `self.logger.warning()` in the Except). `method=HEAD` would not help as the exception occurs in the `Request()` before even reaching the `yield`.

Answer (score 0):

You just check if it starts with `https` and `http`

If not, then prepend `http` manually.

```
if not LINK.startswith('http:') and not LINK.startswith('https:'):
    LINK = "http://" + LINK
```